# Topic is not assigned a partition

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

So I am running my kafka consumer. Im just curious why my topic is not anymore placed inside the partition assigned. I believe when it shows that it is assigned, it means that I am able to listen to that topic. But now, logs are showing that there are no assigned partition for my topic. Am I still able to successfully listen to the topic or not?

Here are the logs:

```
Successfully logged in.
2021-10-01 02:43:14.668  INFO 35404 --- [_user@TEST.COM] o.a.k.c.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin  : [Principal=kafka_user@TEST.COM]: TGT refresh thread started.
2021-10-01 02:43:14.668  INFO 35404 --- [_user@TEST.COM] o.a.k.c.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin  : [Principal=kafka_user@TEST.COM]: TGT valid starting at: Fri Oct 01 02:43:14 CST 2021
2021-10-01 02:43:14.668  INFO 35404 --- [_user@TEST.COM] o.a.k.c.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin  : [Principal=kafka_user@TEST.COM]: TGT expires: Fri Oct 01 12:43:14 CST 2021
2021-10-01 02:43:14.668  INFO 35404 --- [_user@TEST.COM] o.a.k.c.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin  : [Principal=kafka_user@TEST.COM]: TGT refresh sleeping until: Fri Oct 01 11:06:34 CST 2021
2021-10-01 02:43:14.689  INFO 35404 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.3.1
2021-10-01 02:43:14.689  INFO 35404 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 18a913733fb71c01
2021-10-01 02:43:14.690  INFO 35404 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1633027394689
2021-10-01 02:43:14.692  INFO 35404 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=my-group-service-dev] Subscribed to topic(s): MY_TOPIC
2021-10-01 02:43:14.695  INFO 35404 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService
2021-10-01 02:43:14.706  INFO 35404 --- [           main] s.i.k.i.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : started org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter@6ad2c882
2021-10-01 02:43:14.712  INFO 35404 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2021-10-01 02:43:14.751  INFO 35404 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2021-10-01 02:43:14.843  INFO 35404 --- [           main] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
2021-10-01 02:43:15.646  INFO 35404 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http) with context path ''
2021-10-01 02:43:15.648  INFO 35404 --- [           main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8090
2021-10-01 02:43:17.051  WARN 35404 --- [container-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=my-group-service-dev] Connection to node -3 (broker.port3.com/10.235.27.73:6667) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-10-01 02:43:17.388  INFO 35404 --- [           main] com.ap.Application              : Started Application in 62.57 seconds (JVM running for 143.114)
2021-10-01 02:43:17.816  INFO 35404 --- [container-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=my-group-service-dev] Cluster ID: qa_IFa70SgeMIT5JIcDhHA
2021-10-01 02:43:18.213  INFO 35404 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=my-group-service-dev] Discovered group coordinator broker.port1.com:6667 (id: 2147482644 rack: null)
2021-10-01 02:43:18.219  INFO 35404 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=my-group-service-dev] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
2021-10-01 02:43:18.220  INFO 35404 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$1  : my-group-service-dev: partitions revoked: []
2021-10-01 02:43:18.220  INFO 35404 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=my-group-service-dev] (Re-)joining group
2021-10-01 02:43:18.621  INFO 35404 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=my-group-service-dev] (Re-)joining group
2021-10-01 02:43:19.816  INFO 35404 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=my-group-service-dev] Successfully joined group with generation 68
2021-10-01 02:43:19.819  INFO 35404 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=my-group-service-dev] Setting newly assigned partitions: 
2021-10-01 02:43:19.821  INFO 35404 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$1  : my-group-service-dev: partitions assigned: []
```

Comment: If there is another instance of the application with the same group Id, then this instance will get no partitions until that one rebalances

Comment: Starting a new instance with the same group.id will cause a rebalance; however since you are getting no partitions; it appears you don't have enough; only one consumer instance can consume from each partition at the same time. You need at least as many partitions as there are consumer instances.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I saw that the deployed application is also using the same group id thats why it is happening on my local. I can now connect upon changing the group id name. Although does this log mean that there are 1076 messages currently in the topic? "Resetting offset for partition KAFKA_TOPIC-0 to offset 1076."